# Qlik Sense Aggregate and compare values in two fields

Tags: qliksense

In Qlik Sense (charts only) I need some help to identify and calculate occurrences for each ID where values in CODE_A does not match the values in CODE_B.

[image: Data]

Based on my example data, I want a straight table with a row for each ID and the number of "Errors" like this:

[image: Result]

For each ID It's an error, if the values in CODE_A don't have a match in CODE_B. In this case :

- ID 1 is not an error because the value "AA" also is present in CODE_B.
- ID 2 has 1 error because "CC" <> "DD"
- ID 5 has 2 errors    because neither "AA" or "BB" is in CODE_B
- ID 6 has 0 errors because    value "CC" is in both CODE_A and CODE_B

Sample data:

```
Data:
Load *
Inline [ID, CODE_A, CODE_B
1, AA, AA
1, AA, BB
2, CC, DD
3, EE, EE
3, EE, FF
4, FF, FF
4, FF, GG
5, AA, FF
5, BB, GG
6, CC, DD
6, EE, CC
];
```

Answer (score 0):

A very special concept.. If I get you right:

1. You want zero errors counted if at least one CODE_A exists in CODE_B for a given ID. Like IDs 1,3,4,6
2. You want every Code counted in CODE_A if none match with CODE_B for a given ID. Like IDs 2 and 5

Then there are different ways to achieve that.

Backend:

```
Data: 
Load * Inline [ID, CODE_A, CODE_B 
1, AA, AA 
1, AA, BB 
2, CC, DD 
3, EE, EE 
3, EE, FF 
4, FF, FF 
4, FF, GG 
5, AA, FF 
5, BB, GG 
6, CC, DD 
6, EE, CC ];

Left Join
Load ID, CODE_B as CODE_A, 1 as flag
RESIDENT Data;
```

Then in frontend:

Straight table with ID and the following formula

```
Sum(Aggr(If(IsNull(Max(flag)), COUNT(1), 0), ID))
```

And you get:

[image]

I hope that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Very nice, but I have no access to work in the load script. Is it possible to make this in chart expression only.